# An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext when @Scheduled triggered?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-scheduled

I created a `Spring Boot` app and have trouble with some endpoints that can be triggered manually or via `@Scheduled` annotation.

The issue I get is the one below:

> org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException:
>   An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext

Is there a way to trigger `SecurityContext` if the process called via `@Scheduled`?

I am new to `Spring Security` and it is very hard for me to understand the reference guide. I found some similar questions but still cannot understand how to apply answers to my case.

Example of my `MyController`:

```
@Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api")
public class MyController {

    @Scheduled(cron = "* * * * * *")
    @GetMapping(path="/data")
    public void getData() {
        // Do some operations
    }
}
```

Comment: That code makes no sense. `@GetMapping` means that the method is a handler for an HTTP `GET` request, and that it should **return** something to the client. Your method doesn't take any parameters and doesn't return anything, so what is the purpose of it, as a request handler?

Comment: Trigger some background jobs.

Comment: Then it should be a `POST` method, not a `GET` method.

Comment: @Andreas Indeed, you are right!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `@Scheduled` method should not be `@Secured`. Scheduled methods are already in trusted code.

Refactor your code, e.g.

```
@Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api")
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @PostMapping(path="/run")
    public void runJobs() {
        myService.runJobs();
    }
}
```

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    @Scheduled(cron = "* * * * * *")
    public void runJobs() {
        // Do some operations
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Basically you have to configure your scheduler with the necessary authentication. Something in the lines of the following:

```
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.SchedulingConfigurer;
import org.springframework.scheduling.config.ScheduledTaskRegistrar;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.concurrent.DelegatingSecurityContextScheduledExecutorService;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;

import static java.util.concurrent.Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor;
import static org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder.getContext;

@Configuration
public class SchedulerConfiguration implements SchedulingConfigurer {

    private static final String KEY = "spring";
    private static final String PRINCIPAL = "spring";
    private static final List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> AUTHORITIES = ImmutableList.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ADMIN"));

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(final ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
        taskRegistrar.setScheduler(taskExecutor());
    }

    @Bean
    public Executor taskExecutor() {
        final AnonymousAuthenticationToken token = new AnonymousAuthenticationToken(KEY, PRINCIPAL, AUTHORITIES);
        final SecurityContext securityContext = getContext();
        securityContext.setAuthentication(token);
        return new DelegatingSecurityContextScheduledExecutorService(newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(), securityContext);
    }
}
```

Then you can annotate your controller with `@Secured("hasAuthority('ADMIN')")`.