# Saving a record using JPA in a Spring Boot Scheduler

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm using a Spring Boot Scheduler to run a query on the DB daily to find some records based on a condition and update the records returned. Fetching the records using JPA works fine, but when I loop through them, update them, and try to save each updated record I get the following error:
`Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction`

`Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convertCommitException(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:81) at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:104) at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:562) ... 30 more Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.xxx.yyy.config.JpaAuditingConfiguration.auditorProvider$lambda-0(JpaAuditingConfiguration.kt:15) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy168.getCurrentAuditor(Unknown Source) at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:265) at org.springframework.data.auditing.AuditingHandler.getAuditor(AuditingHandler.java:109) at org.springframework.data.auditing.AuditingHandler.markModified(AuditingHandler.java:104) at org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener.touchForUpdate(AuditingEntityListener.java:112)`.

Here is the scheduler code I have. If I run the same code inside my service and call it using an endpoint everything works fine:

```
@Component
class Scheduler(
    private val repository: Repository
) {
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 2 * * *")
    fun expire() {
       val records = repository.findRecords()
       for (record in records) {
            try {
                 // Call some external API using record.id but this part is commented out for now until the saving works
                 record.active = false
                 repository.save(record)
            } catch (ex: Exception) {
                logger.error("Error expiring record " + record.id)
                logger.error("Exception: ${ex.printStackTrace()}")
                continue
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the null pointer exception happens in the `JpaAuditingConfiguration` config I use for storing the created_at and last_modified_at dates. Here is the code I have for that class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "auditorProvider")
class JpaAuditingConfiguration {
    @Bean
    fun auditorProvider(): AuditorAware<String> {
        return AuditorAware { Optional.of(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication.name) }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include the relevant line for `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException`?

Comment: Why do an update in code, just write an update statement instead of a select + retrieve + modify + save. 1 query can do this as well. Also your code is wrong as the find and save are separate transactions. This code is slow as each save is an individual transaction (or 1 large one and then it is wrong as well as you are doing a catch + continue).

Comment: @M.Deinum I am looping through the records because I need to call some external API using the record ID before updating the record and saving. That part of the code is commented out for now because it's not what's causing the issue. I updated my code above and added a comment where the external API is supposed to happen.

Comment: @voidvoid this happens in `JpaAuditingConfiguration` class. I added the lines that show that in the error and added the code I use in that class.

Comment: @Simo when your scheduler is being executed you don't have a principal in the security context, however, when a request is doing this, you have a principal from the session. That's why you're getting the error. Please confirm this so I can post an answer :)

Comment: @voidvoid maybe you're right but I don't understand why the security principal doesn't apply to the scheduler

Comment: @Simo how would it know whom to authenticate? You need to manually authenticate someone, usually you make a separate `app` user for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `JpaAuditingConfiguration` requires the security context to be non null when you make modifications. When you're running your task in a scheduler there is no active request, so no active session, and therefore your authentication is null.
Usually, this is solved by making a special `app` user and manually authenticating them in your scheduled task.

Comment: thank you. I could get it to work thanks to your answer and the answer provided in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58467574/10192704) comment